# Programmatically adding UITextField to a dropdownlist

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

I have a tableview controlled by a UITableViewController.
In this UITableViewController class I have added a `UITextField` programmatically to my UINavigationItem by adding these lines to my viewDidLoad method :

```
CGRect passwordTextFieldFrame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 100.0f, 280.0f, 31.0f);
UITextField *passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:passwordTextFieldFrame];
passwordTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
passwordTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
passwordTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
passwordTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
passwordTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
passwordTextField.tag = 2;
passwordTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
passwordTextField.delegate = self; // ADD THIS LINE
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:passwordTextField];
```

The `UITextField` is displayed correctly on my navigationbar but when I click it the textFieldDidBeginEditing never fires.

I have added the  to my header file along with the textFieldDidBeginEditing method.

I tried doing the exact same thing in a view controlled by UIViewController and here the textFieldDidBeginEditing gets fired when I click the "textfield" - So I suspect the fact that I am adding the textfield to a UITableViewController is what's causing trouble.

You might think - why didn't you add a "uinavigationbutton" to the "NavigationBar" instead - but I can't as the uidropdownmenu that I want to call when the button is being clicked only accepts a "UITextField".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more line:

```
[passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply - but still my breakpoint doesn't get fired inside of textFieldDidBeginEditing when I click the textfield

Comment: The parent view controller must implement this delegate: UITextFieldDelegate - Try implementing it under your enclosing view controller. If that doesn't work then, you would probably need to have it implemented by your navigation bar. And for that to work, you will need to implement a category for UINavigationbar that implements this protocol. Like it is done here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/CreateDirController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-CreateDirController_m-DontLinkElementID_9

Comment: I am inclined to believe the class that you are having passwordTextField, should implement UITextFieldDelegate and it will work. Like @interface YourClass () <UITextFieldDelegate, ANY_OTHER_DELEGATES>. I highly think it will be your UITableViewController derived controller.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I already have added the UITextFieldDelegate protocol to my class - like this:

@interface LMResultsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: I have also tried adding the UITextFieldDelegate to the .m class - like this:
@interface LMResultsTableViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
But still no luck

Comment: Then it would have to be one of UINavigationbar or UINavigationController categories (derived by you) that would have to implement this UITextFieldDelegate protocol, I think.

Comment: Ok - can you explain this solution a bit further - I have the uinavigation view in the storyboard - do I need to add a controller for this view and then add the UITextFieldDelegate protocol to this controller class ?

Comment: I tried it on my box and it worked for me. I have posted step by step on blog: http://iphonegamezone.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/ever-seen-it-text-field-in-navigation-bar/ if you still don't get it, I have put entire code sample at the end of that post - under dropbox folder. Let me know if what you observe.

Comment: Did you get chance to try it?

Comment: It worked - thanks - I finally got it to work just by catching the delegate in my tableview controller. thanks for your help